# How to make an embed image resize with browsers

Tags: image-resizing, onmouseover, autoresize

Here's the code for the embed:

```
<a href="URL"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMAGE1.png"
onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/IMAGE2.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/IMAGE1.png'"/></a>
```

Is there anything I can insert to make this resize properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css properties like `width: 50%` to make it resize to a percentage of its container. That should work for different browser sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. Can't believe it took me so long.

Threw this in right before the first onmouseover:

```
style="width:100%;height:100%;"
```